# Derived constructor warning: will never be executed

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Good day, sirs and mams )

I've just got some strange problem, while proging c++, using Code::Blocks 10.05, FreeBSD 9.1

Source in lib.cpp:

```
class A{
  public:
    A();
    A(var1, var2);
};
A::A(){ imlementation }
A::A(va1, var2) {implementation }
class B : public A{
  public:
    B();
    B(var1, var2);
};
B::B() : A() {} // this is Astr#
B::B(var1, var2) : A(var1, var2) {} // this is Bstr#
```

Source in lib.h:

```
class A{
  public:
    A();
    A(var1, var2);
};
class B : public A{
  public:
    B();
    B(var1, var2);
};
```

Source in main.cpp:

```
#include "lib.h"
...
int main(){
  ...
  B* Bptr = new B();
  B* Bptr2 = new B(var1, var2);
  ...
}
```

And I get these build warnings:

```
.../lib.cpp||In constructor 'B::B(var1, var2)':
.../lib.cpp|Bstr#|warning: will never be executed
.../lib.cpp||In constructor 'B::B(var1, var2)':
.../lib.cpp|Bstr#|warning: will never be executed
.../lib.cpp||In constructor 'B::B()':
.../lib.cpp|Astr#|warning: will never be executed
.../lib.cpp||In constructor 'B::B()':
.../lib.cpp|Astr#|warning: will never be executed
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 4 warnings ===|
```

This warnings appear only in Debug mode, Release build seems goes ok.
The code builds and runs fine, but what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have definitions of class A and class B both in .h and .cpp?

Comment: 1) `B::B(var1, var2) : B {}` this shouldn't be compiled. I think you wanted to write `B::B(var1, var2) : B() {}`. 2) B's constructors are private, thats why `new B` shouldn't be compiled too 3) add types for `var1` and `var2`

Comment: Please try to give working example code.

Comment: @VladimirKolesnikov - it's error-prone, but it's valid. That's essentially what `#include "lib.h"` would do.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor `B(var1,var2)` in lib.h is private.

Comment: I've just missed a "public" line  in lib.h code here and i'm deriving B as public A, why they should be private?

Comment: @DizzzyDozzzer: Because the default is private. When you derive publicly from A, that has no impact on the visibility of B's constructors (since these don't exist in A). You should remove the declaration of B from lib.cpp btw and just keep the definitions. And I see you have edited your code, does the same error still turn up?

Answer (score 0):

> warning: will never be executed

is GCC's warning that can be enabled with `-Wunreachable-code`. `-Wunreachable-code` is very unreliable and should not be used; the whole option was removed altogether for that reason in newer versions of GCC. (Actually, not removed entirely: the command-line option `-Wunreachable-code` is still there, but it no longer does anything.)